# creating a readthedocs.io repo in sync with a public gitlab repo

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, read-the-docs

I have a public gitlab project here
https://gitlab.com/parmentelat/minisim2

I tried to add a corresponding project in `readthedocs.io`, so that a new commit being pushed onto gitlab triggers a doc rebuild on readthedocs

I do this routinely with projects hosted at github and it's really easy - at least under my setup - since readthedocs shows me an updated list of github repos right away, and everything goes smoothly after that.

When trying to import this gitlab project under readthedocs though, I have to chose 'Import manually' as my gitlab projects would not show up.
(In the 'connected services' of my readthedocs settings page, I could find a way to connect to github and to bitbucket; gitlab does not seem supported)

Fair enough, I try this manual import, but at that point no matter how I try to spell the project's URL and what method (git or https) I try to use for importing the project, I get this error message

> This repository doesn't have a valid webhook set up. That means it won't be rebuilt on commits to the repository. 
>   You can resync your webhook to fix this.

is what I am trying to do doable at all ?

do I need to do something specific on the gitlab side

thanks for any hint

Comment: Obviously this has nothing to do with the project's URL as attached to the readthedocs instance, since I can successfully trigger a manual doc build. I fancy what is only missing now is a webhook declared more or less manually on the gitlab side, but I have not yet figured how exactly to go about doing that

Comment: I managed to do that by following the tip here - thanks to #destroyerofbuilds on github - https://github.com/destroyerofbuilds/readthedocs.org/blob/12f7706b4e179d6dcf3d8ae0c37efbc155134453/docs/webhooks.rst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually set the webhook on gitlab.com:

- Click the settings icon for your project
- Select "Integrations"
- Enter the above URL, select "Push events" and "Enable SSL verification"
- Click "Add Webhook"

That should do it.